# В чем заключается ошибка функции?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Помогите пжл.

Есть код:

```
$(".desk #window").each(function(i,v){
            $(this).on('click', function(e){
                function getInfo() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "desk.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {char: $(e.target).data("char")},
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(html){
                            $(".tickets").html(html);
                        }
                    });

                }
                getInfo();
                setInterval(getInfo,1000);
            });
        });`
```

При обращении к файлу "desk.php", функция возвращает из БД значения типа: A001, Б002 и т.д. в соответствии с выбранным окном. Но если, например, есть несколько значений начинающихся с одной буквы, типа А001, А002, А003 и т.д., то функция возвращает их все в блок с классом "tickets". 
Вот PHP код обработчика:

```
class Desk{

public static function getWindow($char){
        $getVal = R::findAll("counter","`value` LIKE ? ORDER BY `id`", ["$char%"]);
        return $getVal ? $getVal : false;
    }

}
$getTickets = Desk::getWindow($_POST['char']);
if($getTickets) {
    foreach ($getTickets as $k => $v) {
        echo $v['value'] . '<br>';
    }
}else{
    echo "Очередь отсутствует";
}
```

Когда нужно посмотреть все (будем называть их билетами) билеты(A001, A002...) одного окна, то все работает нормально, но когда смотрим билеты другого окна, то в блок с классом "tickets" сначала записываются билеты из 1-го окна, после записываются все билеты второго окна, и каждую секунду так происходит, сначала из 1-го, потом со 2-го окон. Если нажимать на каждое окно, то появляются билеты каждого окна. 
setInterval здесь нужен для того, чтобы все билеты обновлялись каждую секунду по мере поступления записи в БД. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на определенное окно, и далее выбора другого окна, появлялись билеты только текущего окна, а не от предыдущих и текущего?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var timer; // !!!
$(".desk #window").each(function(i, v) {
  $(this).on('click', function(e) {
    function getInfo() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "desk.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
          char: $(e.target).data("char")
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
          $(".tickets").html(html);
        }
      });

    }
    timer = clearInterval(timer); // !!!
    getInfo();
    timer = setInterval(getInfo, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! ты лучший!

Comment: а можешь подсказать, каким образом это получилось? в чем логика работы?

Comment: @Suleyman Ключевой момент - выключение предыдущего таймера `clearInterval(timer);` перед запуском следующего.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @Suleyman Пожалуйста. Успехов!